# TMB c++ code in R package and CRAN checks

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, tmb

I am working on an R package to include c++ templates created in TMB. Using the helpful guidelines shared in [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627069/guidelines-for-including-tmb-c-code-in-an-r-package), I managed to come a very long way.

At the moment, I'm using 2 c++ templates ("kglmer.cpp" and "nglmer.cpp") and the following Makefile.win (and equivalent Makefile) to create the dll's:

```
all: kglmer.dll nglmer.dll

kglmer.dll: kglmer.cpp
    Rscript --vanilla -e "TMB::compile('kglmer.cpp', '-O1 -g',DLLFLAGS='')"
nglmer.dll: nglmer.cpp
    Rscript --vanilla -e "TMB::compile('nglmer.cpp', '-O1 -g',DLLFLAGS='')"

clean:
    rm -rf *o
```

However, when running CRAN checks (using `devtools::check()`), I receive the following warning:

```
checking if this is a source package ...
     Subdirectory '/src' contains apparent object files/libraries
     kglmer.dll nglmer.dll
Object files/libraries should not be included in a source package.
```

The issue seems to be related to not properly cleaning the src folder. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: you could try putting `*.dll` (or `src/*.dll`?) in `.Rbuildignore` …

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! 
`*.dll` is not accepted by `.Rbuildignore`. `src/*.dll` is, but does not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The`clean` targets should match the `all` target, i.e. in `Makefile.win` you should have

```
clean:
    rm -rf *.dll
```

Comment: Indeed. And/or add the optional script `cleanup` at your package top-level and have it call `rm` on build artefacts.