# How to make compiled TMB C++ code portable among platforms

Tags: package, tmb

I've been following the link ([Guidelines for including TMB c++ code in an R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48627069/guidelines-for-including-tmb-c-code-in-an-r-package)) to include a .cpp TMB model into my R package (fishmethods).
I got it to work on Windows using a Makefile.win file with the code:

```
all: EP_likelihood.dll
        # Comment here preserves the prior tab
EP_likelihood.dll: EP_likelihood.cpp
        Rscript --vanilla -e "TMB::compile('EP_likelihood.cpp','-O0 -g',DLLFLAGS='')"
clean:
        rm -rf *.dll
```

and, in the Description file, setting

```
LinkingTo: TMB
```

and adding "TMB" to the *Imports:" line.  Also, I added to the "Namespace" file

```
importFrom("TMB","MakeADFun","sdreport")
```

and

```
useDynLib(EP_likelihood).
```

I am able to build and install the package on Windows. I want to make the .cpp model portable across platforms because the updated package will be put on CRAN. I've been reading the "Writing R Extensions" manual particularly under "Writing Portable Packages" but I don't understand fully what I have to do (I am not a professional programmer).   Would anyone have any suggestions or have an example that I could examine?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I used TMBtools to create an example of a R package with CPP files and then copied the different statements I needed from the NAMESPACE, etc. files.